# Python subpixel-accurate image crop

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I need to crop an image with subpixel accuracy. For example, I might need to create an interpolated rectangular crop with corners (108.5, 350.9) and (368.3, 230.1) out of an image with dimensions 640x480. How can I achieve this?

Edit: It's a reasonable concession to stretch the cropped area to fit it into a data matrix. However you can't just change the borders of the crop to integer coordinates.

Comment: How do you intend to represent the partial pixels in the output?

Comment: @MarkRansom Good question, I suppose image formats don't allow the image to have different horizontal and vertical dpi's. The next best thing might be to slightly stretch the crop to an integer number of pixels. So, after cropping, scale up/down each dimension to the nearest pixel.

Comment: of course you can have different dpi in vertical and horizontal direction. but dpi is not related to pixels or their values its a conversion factor...

Comment: @Piglet You're right, but then the image crop should come out fine. The matrix representation would be a distorted version of the image and the horizontal and vertical dpis could offset the distortion to bring the crop to its proper aspect ratio.

Comment: dpi has nothing to do with cropping

Comment: @Piglet it's necessary for subpixel cropping. There is no way to scale up a subpixel crop to an integer number of pixels along each dimension, so you have to distort the image into an integer number of pixels and then offset the distortion with different dpis along the dimensions.

Comment: DPI stands for dots per inch. it is just a conversion factor. you may get sub-pixel values if you convert some distance into pixels but that is by no means related to cropping images

Comment: @Piglet What I'm referring to is, say for example you performed this crop and you end up with a normal jpeg, but with the horizontal axis stretched by a factor of 1.009 and the vertical axis stretched by a factor of 0.99923 with dpi of 300 along both dimensions. Then you end up with a slightly stretched image. I was suggesting that you might change the horizontal dpi to 300*1.009 and the vertical dpi to 300*0.99923 to undistort the image. I'm not suggesting that this is possible, but it could be a solution to this cropping problem.

Comment: @Piglet I don't know if this kind of thing would be referred to dpi or ppi or something else, I'm not an expert in image processing.

Comment: If you don't know what you want, perhaps you can tell us a little more - why do you need subpixel boundaries, and what will you do with the output? Your problem is not very common and it's remarkably underspecified at the moment.

Comment: @Mark Ransom All that is required for the problem is to select anny arbitrary rectangle inside of an image and create a pixel matrix containing only that portion of the image. The ideal output would be a simple numpy.ndarray containing the desired portion of the image. The only complicating factor is to allow subpixel boundaries. This would probably require stretching each dimension of the image selection to fit it into a matrix of discrete pixels. That's all that I need.

Comment: you seem to have some misconception. you cannot stretch an image using dpi or ppi or whatever. an image has discrete pixels. there is no stretching.

Comment: @Piglet Yes I know they have discrete pixels.. in other words, you can stretch a 100x100 image to a 100x200 image and still have discrete pixels. I don't see what I'm not conveying properly.

Comment: yes you can do that but that's not related to dpi or ppi or whatever. and you were talking about stretching an image to integer coordinates which doesn't make sense as there are no images with non-integer pixel dimensions. maybe you should add your actual problem to your question because no one can think of any use case of what you want and it is most likely some misconception your side that makes you think you need sub-pixel cropping...

Comment: @Piglet I am 100% certain that I need sub-pixel cropping. I mean I don't *need* it, but it would be useful. You say there are no images with non-pixel dimensions but a subpixel crop has non-integer pixel dimensions. It isn't necessary to talk about what I'm using it for to ask for a solution to a clear computational problem, so I won't talk about the application, sorry.

Comment: It is *absolutely* necessary to talk about the application when the thing you're asking for is so outside of everybody's normal experience. We need to understand the problem completely, and so far you're not helping. P.S. you do realize that stretching the image will result in degradation of the entire image, not just the edges, right?

Comment: @Mark Ransom For my application, I can afford to use a high-quality image scaling method that doesn't result in much degradation. Sorry that I didn't explain the problem clearly enough without talking about the application; I thought the edit was clear.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while but I don't have a good answer. Determining the value at a non-integer coordinate requires interpolation, which is part of every resizing operation. The problem is that the resizing code doesn't give you the ability to specify start/stop coordinates. I was thinking there might be a way to resize much larger and just pick out the points you need, but I can't think of a good way to do that.

Comment: @MarkRansom The solution is basically 1. Calculate the top and left margins of the crop in pixels, then 2. Scale the whole image horizontally and vertically until the top left coordinate is an integer coordinate. 3. Crop out the top left coordinate up to the bottom right corner of the image. 4. Calculate the new bottom and right margins of the crop in pixels 5. Scale the new image horizontally and vertically until the bottom right corner of the crop is an integer coordinate. 6. Do the crop with integer coordinates as you normally would

Comment: OK, that works. Doing two scaling operations is sub-optimal though - the degradation will be doubled. If you can live with that I guess you found your solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom Of course it would be better if a library did it without having to do two scaling operations, so I don't know how to do it *optimally*. This works without needing a special library though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if I can call this an answer because I don't really know what your question is but I try to shed some light on you.

So I guess your problem arises from some misconception.

First of all DPI, PPI or whatever you want to use is nothing but a factor that tells you how many dots, points, pixels you have per inch. That factor allows you to determin print sizes or convert between pixel dimensions and inch dimensions. 
That's by no means related to cropping an image.

Cropping a rectangular region is a very common task.
Also having ROIs with sub-pixel coordinates is pretty common as their coordinates often arise from calculations that yield non-integer values.

Usually you simply round coordinates to integers so your problem vanishes.

If you want to get intensity values for sub-pixel coordinates you can interpolate between neigbouring pixels. But as images cannot have half pixels you will have to store that information in an image that has more or less pixels.

So here's what I would do if I didn't want to use rounded coordinates.

If my coordinate is >= x.5 I'd add a column or row, otherwise I'd skip the pixel.
If I would add a column or row I would interpolate it's values.

But to be honest I don't see any use case for this and I never had to do anything but using integer coordinates for cropping in my career.

You cannot print fractions of pixels and you cannot display them either, so what's the point?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but there actually are legitimate cases where you need to select subpixel values. It's fine to stretch the selection to an integer number of pixels but it would have to be done without adding in neighboring pixel information. This is necessary for example when you're working with crops that are very small size, e.g. 100x100. It is not for making large Photoshop images or anything like that.

Comment: @JosephValles please don't tell me that there are legitimate cases. name them... which use cases are you talking about? what is the problem you want to solve doing that and what is the point of using sub-pixel coordinates if you don't interpolate values? that's nonsense...

Comment: Interpolation would almost certainly be necessary to do a subpixel crop. However, pixel information that isn't inside of the crop area shouldn't just be thrown into the cropped area. That wouldn't be a clean solution.

Comment: @JosephValles no one said you would include non-selected pixels... if you crop rows 1-10.5 then you should include information from row 11... otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to use 10.5. you could just use 10... why else would you select parts of that row. but no one said that you should use row 12... so I don't understand your last comment at all.

Comment: Yes that is the correct method, all I am saying is that you shouldn't just round the row to 11, and you should only interpolate information from rows 1 to 10.5. I laid out the details in my own answer.

Comment: @JosephValles  you cannot interpolate to 10.5 because there is no information at 10.5. that's why you have to interpolate in the first place... and if you don't include row 11 to your cropped output why select beyond 10`????

Comment: I guess I'm saying that you "only include half" of row 11 in the interpolation. We're probably talking about the same thing. Anyway, the problem's already been solved, so there's nothing to argue about. I think your answer was ambiguous about "adding a row" for half-pixel values.

Comment: @JosephValles I am not argueing. I'm just having a university degree in image-processing and > 10 years of experience and I tell you that you are talking non-sense and that your solution is non-sense. I don't want to sound rude or arrogant but you very obviously lack some important basic knowledge which casues misconceptions and really awkward solutions.

Comment: I don't think the solution is nonsense. It solves the problem perfectly. Maybe there's a misunderstanding somewhere. Anyway, have a good day. :)

Comment: It's true that I don't know all the terminology in image processing so that may have caused some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to require that you calculate the center of the rectangle that you want to crop out of the image, and the height and width of the rectangle as well. Then just scale up the entire image until the desired rectangle has integer dimensions, then do a usual crop. You will have to scale the horizontal and vertical dimensions by separate amounts, so this will slightly distort the cropped portion and you will have to adjust for the distortion in the image encoding format you use.